# How to properly proxy file bucket with Nextjs so I can catch not found errors?

Tags: next.js, proxy, google-cloud-storage

I use google cloud storage (which I'm proxying with Next.js) for storing assets and the problem is that if key (file) is entered incorrectly google cloud throws error message which exposes my bucket, that I don't want to happen.

```
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
  <Details>No such object: my_secret_bucket/asset.svg</Details>
</Error>
```

Here is how my Nextjs 14 proxy configuration looks like -

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/assets/photos/:path*',
        destination: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/my_secret_bucket/:path*'
      }
    ]
  },
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/assets/photos',
        destination: '/404',
        permanent: false
      }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

How to catch that "NoSuchKey" error and redirect to 404 page????

thanks in advance

Comment: With this setup, you can't, because you're depending on the browser's behavior for loading that URL, and your code isn't involved at all during that process.

Comment: Your code is redirecting the client. That means the client already knows the bucket name before the error message. Do not rely on obscurity, read this article: [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).